# Shrinkwrap an image onto a corner of a cube (so on 3 sides at the same time)

Tags: image, shrinkwrap

I know how to shrinkwrap an image onto a curved or flat surface but when trying to get good results by shrinkwrapping onto the corner of a cube I have problems. I want the image to be on 3 sides: on the front, on the top and on the side of the cube. However the shrinkwrap modifier is probably not the correct solution for this or I am missing something.

How can I map the image onto the surface?

[image: Steps taken]

Comment: Could always try using edge loops on a duplicated cube to get the right shape. Then press p to detach it. Then use project from view on it?

Comment: @NascentSpace Could you elaborate on that? I cannot follow you right now. :)

Comment: does it need to be a separate object? don't you want to make the wave image part of the cube material?

Comment: @moonboots Normally I would try to UV unwrap the cube and paste the wave via an image texture but it won't work respectively the wave is then not displayed as I assumed. That is the reason why I just try to project it onto the corner and see what results I can get.

Comment: mmh you should be able to do it easily with a UV map, what was the problem with your attempt?

Comment: Perhaps I unwrapped the cube in a wrong way. Theoretically what I need to have in order to place the wave correctly are no seams along the corner facing the camera but that's not how uv unwrapping works in my understanding.